# How is the neat way to add "..." after a cropped text inside DIV?

Tags: jquery, css, html, text, crop

I need to show "stub" description texts beside product images. But I need to cut it in 3 lines high if it's very long (or less, if the description is just a short text). But the problem is the field dimension for the text may vary. And other problem is I have to add "..." on the end of the stub text.

The current CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="box">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in egestas diam, et gravida ligula. Nullam fermentum eget purus consectetur semper. Morbi ut adipiscing purus. Sed lobortis nulla erat, pulvinar pharetra mauris porttitor sagittis. Morbi pellentesque dui quis tortor feugiat, eu malesuada dui faucibus. Integer magna nisi, cursus ac diam accumsan, hendrerit laoreet nibh. In commodo lorem massa, eget semper tellus cursus a. Proin sagittis consectetur sapien ut congue. Vivamus cursus tellus in pellentesque hendrerit. Curabitur placerat tincidunt porta. Nunc pulvinar odio at enim imperdiet vulputate.</div>
```

The HTML result with the current CSS:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec in egestas diam, et
```

The HTML result intended:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.
Donec in egestas diam, et ...
```

What do you think is the neat way to do this, which mean it's flexible / expandable in the future? I have HTML, CSS, JSP, Javascript, and JQuery at my disposal. But I can't, by any means, alter the data inside the database. But of course I can manipulate any data I receive from the database before I present it to the user.

Comment: There should be a jQuery plugin for that.

Comment: You could take a look at something similar, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/t4CQt/7/

Comment: This may help - http://www.mobify.com/blog/multiline-ellipsis-in-pure-css/

Comment: @BramVanroy Ya, it might help in the other parts of my projects. Thank you! :)

Comment: @pandit The CSS code is great! I think I'm going to use this one. Too bad you didn't put it as an answer, just a comment. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChenLiYong This will work only for single line code, you are asking about multiple line code.

Comment: @pandit I don't really understand what you meant with "multiple line codes", but from what I saw on your link, it was what I'm looking for: a single long text which was wrapped in multiple lines and can be limited to some lines, and add ellipsis on the end. :)

Comment: @pandit I just have one quick follow up question though; I still curious, which part of the CSS in the link you give me that makes the ellipsis showed when hidden overflowing occurs, and hide it when there's no overflowing that needs to be hide?

Comment: @ChenLiYong that css code will work only in case of single line text.

Comment: @pandit yeah, you mean, the `text-overflow:ellipsis;` one? Maybe not that one that I meant. It may have something to do with the CSS code inside pseudo-class selector :after, but I don't understand which part of it. But, well, in the end, I finally use the JQuery solution (trunc8.js), to have a more reliable solution. But thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a nice jQuery plugin for that, see http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

Comment: This one is great too! Although I prefer the other CSS solution in this page, but this one also counts as a great answer. Why I never knew this plugin in the first place... hmm...

Answer (score 3):

I'll also throw my hat in with the [Trunk8 plugin](http://jrvis.com/trunk8/)

Example usage for you:

```
$('.box').trunk8();
```

Comment: The trunc8 is another neat JQuery solution, and maybe I will try to use this if the CSS solution convoluted the code too much. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think my way isn't perfect but you can do that in CSS only :

```
#longText{
    width : 400px;  height : 200px; overflow: hidden; position : relative;
}

#longText:after{
    content: '...'; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

With a [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hN5Fj/)

Comment: Although your way "isn't perfect", but you give me inspiration for trying something else with your method. And by far, your method is the simplest, neatest and cleanest of all! Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, i've found some interresting things in stackoverflow, with using `text-overflow` in a `display:-webikit-box` but I'm afraid by compatibility with other brother like FF or IE

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3 there is a property called `text-overflow` and it has a property `ellipsis` that adds "..." to the end of the clipped text.

Unfortunately, in general it works only on one line.
But in return it's very easy, needs no Javascript and [has a great browser support](http://caniuse.com/text-overflow).

You can check out the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Py4e/) I made for your example or just use the following CSS-code:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```